# ARkit SCNMorpher isn't working for me. No errors, just no shape changes

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm trying a simple example using SCNMorpher to blend between to poly spheres. They are identical in topology except for the position of the points

Each is stored in a .scn file and I get the shapes like:

```
sphereNode = SCNReferenceNode(named: "sphere")
sphereNode2 = SCNReferenceNode(named: "sphere2")
sphereNode?.morpher = SCNMorpher()
sphereNode!.morpher?.targets = [(sphereNode2?.childNodes.first!.geometry)!]
sphereNode!.name = "EFFECT"
```

I'm using the faceAnchor blend shapes to drive it

```
if let effectNode = sceneView?.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "EFFECT", recursively: true) {
    let v = faceAnchor?.blendShapes[ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation.jawOpen]
    effectNode.morpher?.setWeight(v as! CGFloat, forTargetNamed: "sphere2")
}
```

I've also tried:

```
...
effectNode.morpher?.setWeight(v as! CGFloat, forTargetAt: 0)
...
```

The code runs.. I can print values for v.. they change as I open/close my jaw and that value is passed to the morpher. I see the base sphere shape but it never deforms toward the sphere2 shape.  Am I suppose to do anything else to force it to redraw or calc the deformation?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. looks like I was attaching the morpher to the parent of the shape, not the actual sphere..  funny how asking a question here sometimes creates that "Ah Ha" moment.  Reading in my spheres like this fixed it:

```
sphereNode = SCNReferenceNode(named: "sphere").childNodes.first
sphereNode2 = SCNReferenceNode(named: "sphere2").childNodes.first
sphereNode?.morpher = SCNMorpher()
sphereNode!.morpher?.targets = [(sphereNode2.geometry)!]
sphereNode!.name = "EFFECT"
```